# how to create a table at runtime in oracle sql developer

Tags: oracle, runtime, oracle-sqldeveloper, temporary-objects

How can i create a temporary table at run time with as many columns as count from select query returns?
For example, at starting time it is not known how many items my select query will return as the user inputs it returns number of items under the search criteria that user has entered. So every item's information is to be stored in different columns therefore i need to create a table at run time.
Please suggest how it can be done?

Comment: You want CREATE TABLE MYTABLE as SELECT ..... (Your query)?? by the way, every SQL is executed on runtime only. so if you are able to form the SQL in runtime., you can execute it too.

Comment: Creating tables at runtime isn't usually a good idea, and temporary tables are not usually necessary in Oracle. You might need a collection instead; what will you be doing with the table? Why do you want one column per *row* returned by the query?

Comment: @ alex:because the business wants the result to be returned like that...they want it to be represented like that..and temporary tables are being used because this is needed for the report generation ..the data has to deleted automatically when the session ends..

Comment: I don't understand why you'd want one column per row though. How many rows would you return, one per column in the select list? SO it's a sort of pivot? Or do you mean you just don't now how many items are in the query's select list? If that is the case then presenting the data as a ref cursor might be more appropriate, if your report tool can handle that.